# Why does my value change when I assign it to list's first index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The return value of my defined function `ThreeByThree` changes and adds up by 1 when I assign it to `newImage` list's first (`[0][0]`) index. However, the consecutive assignments are valid. Please see to my print statement results

```
def boxBlur(image):
  lenVert = len(image)
  lenHorz = len(image[0])
  newImage = [[0] * (lenHorz - 2)] * (lenVert - 2)
  def ThreeByThree(a,b,image):
    k = 0
    total = 0
    for i in range(a, a + 3):
      for j in range(b, b + 3):
        k = image[i][j]
        total += k
    return int(total / 9)

  for i in range(0, lenVert - 2):
    for j in range(0, lenHorz - 2):
      print(ThreeByThree(i, j, image))
      newImage[i][j] = ThreeByThree(i, j, image)  # This is where the assignment goes wrong
  return newImage

image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]
print(boxBlur(image))
```

Expected Output:

```
5
4
4
4
 [[5, 4], [4, 4]]
```

Output:

```
5
4
4
4
 [[4, 4], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `newImage` list you are creating using the `*` operator is creating sublists that reference each other. As a result, you actually change the value of `newImage[0][0]` when you assign `newImage[1][0]` since they reference each other. For example:

```
newImage = [[0] * 2] * 2

newImage[0][0] = 5
print(newImage)
# [[5, 0], [5, 0]]

newImage[1][0] = 4
print(newImage)
# [[4, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Instead, create your initial list without the sublists referencing each other (you can still use the `*` operator to multiply the integer values inside the sublist since they are immutable).

```
newImage = [[0] * (lenHorz - 2) for _ in range(lenVert - 2)]
```